# "Invalid Form Body In embed.fields.0.value: This field is required", however I am fairly certain the field is not empty

Tags: python, discord.py

```
import os
from keep_alive import keep_alive
from discord.ext import commands
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime
import discord

bot = commands.Bot(
    command_prefix="!",  # Change to desired prefix
    case_insensitive=True  # Commands aren't case-sensitive
)

bot.author_id = 581512730343637083  # Change to your discord id!!!

channelID = "688698168996921368"

@bot.event 
async def on_ready():  # When the bot is ready
    print("I'm in")
    print(bot.user)  # Prints the bot's username and identifier
    while True:
      time.sleep(2)#
      updateEmbedSaved = check_update()

      if channelID != None and updateEmbedSaved != None:
        try:
          channel = bot.get_channel(int(channelID))
          await channel.send(embed=updateEmbedSaved)
        except Exception as e:
          print(e)
          pass

def check_update():
  todayDate = datetime.today().strftime('%Y.%m.%d')
  todayDate = "2021.06.08"
  csgoPage = requests.get("https://blog.counter-strike.net/index.php/category/updates/")
  html = csgoPage.text
  soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
  dateElems = soup.find_all('p', class_="post_date")
  if dateElems[0].text[:10] == todayDate:
    with open("detected.txt") as f:
      data = f.readline()

    if data != todayDate:
      print("True")
      todayDateSplice = f"/{todayDate[:4]}/{todayDate[5:7]}/"
      linkElems = soup.find_all('a', href=True)
      for index, linkElem in enumerate(linkElems):
        link = linkElem['href']
        if todayDateSplice in link:
          correctLink = link
          break

      csgoPage = requests.get(correctLink)
      html = csgoPage.text
      soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

      titleElems = soup.find_all('h2')

      updateEmbed = discord.Embed(title=f"Update Detected: {titleElems[0].text}", color=0x00ff55)
      updateEmbed.set_thumbnail(url='https://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/730/capsule_616x353.jpg?t=1623182945')
      updateEmbed.set_author(name="CS:GO Update Detected")
      updateEmbed.set_footer(text="CS:GO Update Checker Bot | Information from https://blog.counter-strike.net/")
      paraElems = soup.find_all('p')

      paraElems = paraElems[:len(paraElems)-4]

      for elem in paraElems:
        print(elem.text, "\n-------------")
        body = "\n".join(elem.text.split("\n")[1:])
        if body != None and elem.text.split("\n")[0] != None:
          try:
            updateEmbed.add_field(name=elem.text.split("\n")[0], value=body, inline=False)
          except:
            pass

      with open('detected.txt', 'w') as file:
            file.writelines(todayDate)
      return updateEmbed

  else:
    print("False")
    print(dateElems[0].text[:10])
    print(todayDate)
  
  

keep_alive()  # Starts a webserver to be pinged.
token = os.environ.get("DISCORD_BOT_SECRET") 
bot.run(token)  # Starts the bot
```

Can someone please help me, the error is called when the embed is being sent, and the try except catches it, but the embed is not sent. I have checked that the values going into fields are not empty, yet I still get the error:
"400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In embed.fields.0.value: This field is required"

Can someone help?

Comment: Instead of checking if `body != None`, check `body != ""`. Comparing any string (also empty ones!) to `!= None` will always return `True`.
Your error message also states that the **first** field has an empty value. Maybe this helps?

Comment: Not related to the problem, the comment above ^ answers it, but for `None`-checks you should use `is None` and `is not None` instead of `==` and `!=`.

Answer (score -1):

**I don't know if it works but try this**

Change line 78 with this:

```
updateEmbed.add_field(name=elem.text.split("\n"), value=body, inline=False)
```

I deleted the specific index brackets, but if you want a specific index from it, I really don't know.